# DateAdd converting query from sql to oracle(sql developer)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to migrate my sql query to oracle but it seems That i cannot convert my query due to DateAdd function.
`STRINGVARIABLE = '1361439468476'`

output is : `Feb 20,2013`

```
convert (char(12), (dateadd(s, convert(bigint, STRINGVARIABLE) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))), 107)
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATEADD` doesn't exist in Oracle. There are various ways to manipulate dates, but this is fairly straightforward:

```
select date '1970-01-01' + (to_number('1361439468476') / (1000*60*60*24))
from dual;

DATE'1970
---------
21-FEB-13
```

... which is actually `21/02/2013 09:37:48`, so not sure why you have it as `20-FEB-13`.

If you want to keep the millisecond precision you can use a `TIMESTAMP` instead:

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
    + numtodsinterval(to_number('1361439468476')/1000, 'SECOND')
from dual;

TIMESTAMP'1970-01-0100:00:00'+NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_NUMBER('1361439468476')/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
21-FEB-13 09.37.48.476000000
```

I'm not sure what the `107` in your query is doing though, or convert, perhaps they are formatting the result as a string?

---

OK, I see [what `convert(..., 107)` is doing](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/); the equivalent is:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01'
    + (to_number('1361439468476') / (1000*60*60*24)), 'Mon DD, YYYY') as dt
from dual;

DT
------------
Feb 21, 2013
```

... using [`to_char()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions198.htm) with a `Mon DD, YYYY` [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements004.htm#insertedID2).